# What is the best way to add "last_imported" field into a view for a node entity-reference field joined to migrate_map table?

Tags: views, migrations

I have a node which has an entity-reference field. The enitity in that field is being imported via Migration framework.

So if I call that entity fruit. MyNode has a field call fruit. Which is being migrated from an up-stream. Thus, it has a "migrate_map" table call "migrate_map_fruit".

In which it has a column call "sourceid" which can be joined to "fruit.id" and then I want to extract a field call "last_imported" and display in the view.

What would be the best way to bring it to views ?

It's quite complex so feel free to reach me if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution to that.

You have to add relationship to referenced "fruit" entity to the view. And immediately following field will be available.

In my **fruits_import.module.php** I added hook_view_data() as follows.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
function fruits_import_views_data() {
  $views_data = [];
  // Exposing Migrate Map table.
  $views_data['migrate_map_fruit']['table'] = [
    'title' => t('Related migration'),
    'group' => t('Fruit Entity Migration Tables.'),
    // Watch out! This is not a base table, so we use a different key and
    // explain to Views how this table can be JOINed to our base table of
    // 'fruit'.
    'join'  => [
      // We are explaining Views how 'migrate_map_fruit' can be JOINed to 'fruit'.
      // By the way, you do not necessarily have to JOIN onto a base table. You
      // may as well JOIN in chain a few non-base tables. Although for a table
      // to become visible in Views UI, it must be connected one way or another
      // to a base table on which the view is being built.
      'fruit' => [
        // Column from 'fruit' table which will participate in the JOIN clause.
        'left_field' => 'id',
        // Column from 'migrate_map_fruit' table that will participate in the JOIN
        // clause.
        'field'      => 'destid1',
      ],
    ],
  ];
  // Exposing last imported col only for now. (We could expose other ones here)
  $views_data['migrate_map_fruit']['last_imported'] = [
    // Human friendly name for Views UI.
    'title' => t('Last Imported'),
    'help' => t('Timestamp for an fruit last imported.'),
    'field' => [
      // In the 'id' key we place the name of Views field plugin that is
      // responsible for operating the column. The id "date"
      // corresponds to \Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\Date class. It is
      // an extremely simplistic straightforward field plugin that appends the
      // column into SELECT query (see ::query() method) and then displays the
      // fetched column as field output (see ::render() method).
      'id' => 'date',
    ],
  ];
  return $views_data;
}
```

Credits to awesome Views [tutorial](https://medium.com/oleksandr-trotsenko/drupal-8-views-tutorial-for-developers-part-ii-tables-fields-8c753ea38612) by Oleksandr